# How to add time by value in Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
var now = moment();
var fiveMinutesLater = now.add(5, 'minutes');
now === fiveMinutesLater // --> true
```

From the above, `now` and `fiveMinutesLater` are the same object reference and containing the same value.

Instead of modifying the original moment object, can I have `add()` returning a new moment object with new value?

That is, after line 2, `fiveMinutesLater` is really 5 minutes later than `now`.

Comment: save the now in other var and modify it other one not the original one.

Answer (score 0):

[Clone](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/) it. Try this:

```
var fiveMinutesLater = moment(now).add(5, 'minutes');
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to mention that I have already try this workaround. But I have noticed that cloning would lead to efficiency issue, especially with looping

Comment: @kit—you asked for a new object: "*…can I have add() returning a new moment object with new value…*", but now you don't want a new object?

Comment: It's okay and actually works, I just hope there will be other solutions.